# Asking a user to make an iOS app full screen for functionality

Tags: search, ios, ipad, fullscreen

When trying to search in Apple's Podcasts.app in split screen mode on the iPad or iPad Pro it displays this message:

> To browse or search for podcasts, make Podcasts full screen.

Is there a technical or UX reason for this message? What are the considerations for when to show this message if it is an UX issue?

[image: ss]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App Store is based on webViews to easily update the store on iOS devices and desktops (iTunes, web) So the search results and charts as well as highlights in the podcast app might be presented as web views too and therefor can't be displayed properly in different size classes.

Usually apps that use size classes and have the ability to be presented in split view should provide a great UX for all sizes. Also, I would expect Apple to adapt their own apps for multiple iOS-devices with size classes.

If you're using a native app, this app only lives on the device(s) which is was developed for. So there should'nt be any restrictions in terms of the experience, no matter on which size class the content is presented. It is different with responsive websites though since you can view the site on so many different devices, have different load times and you should'nt display **all** content on **all** devices - The content should adapt to the device it is presented on.

Comment: Huh, I'm still seeing it on 9.2.

Comment: I added a screenshot on 9.2.

Comment: Alright, I actually thought you were referring to searching within your content. Sorry about that. Well, then it makes more sense actually. The App Store is based on webViews to easily update the store on iOS devices and desktops (iTunes, web) So the search results and charts as well as highlights might be presented as web views too and therefor can't be displayed properly in different size classes

Comment: I edited my answer based on your screenshot now